# Polynomial and Permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, modular-arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Let $p$ a prime odd number,  $P\in (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)[x]$ with $\deg(P)<p$ and $P(x)=a_0+\dots+a_{p−1}x^{p−1}$. Is it true if $a_{p−1}\neq 0$ then the polynomial function associed to $P$ is not a permutation of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: Here is a reference in 2 parts: (R. Lidl and G. L. Mullen. When does a polynomial over a finite field permute the elements
of the field? The American Math. Monthly, 95(3), 243-246, 1988) (R. Lidl and G. L. Mullen. When does a polynomial over a finite field permute the elements
of the field? II The American Math. Monthly, 100(1), 71-74, 1993). I wish you can reach them (I can't).

Comment: @JeanMarie : salut, tu sais pourquoi il ferme ce fil ?

Comment: Hopefuly, because some people have considered that this question should come with some personal remarks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that polynomial $P(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_{p-1}x^{p-1}$ with $a_{p-1}\neq 0$ satisfies the condition
$$
P(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Then, it's clear that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}P(k)\equiv \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}k=\frac{p(p-1)}{2}\equiv 0\pmod p.
$$
However, it's well-known that for $m\ge 1$
$$
0^m+1^m+\ldots+(p-1)^m\equiv
\begin{cases}
0,& p-1\nmid m,
\\
-1,& p-1\mid m.
\end{cases}
$$
Hence,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}P(k)\equiv a_0\cdot p+a_1\cdot 0+\ldots+a_{p-2}\cdot 0+a_{p-1}\cdot (-1)\equiv -a_{p-1}.
$$
Thus, $a_{p-1}\equiv 0\pmod p$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

For an odd prime $p$, let
$$
P=a_0+\cdots+a_{p-1}x^{p-1}\in (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)[x]
$$
and suppose that $P$, when regarded as a function from $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, is a permutation of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

**Claim:**$\;a_{p-1}=0$.

**Proof:**

For $k\in\{0,...,p-1\}$, let $X_k=\{0,...,p-1\}{\large{\setminus}}\{k\}$.

By Lagrange interpolation
$$
P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}P(k)\bigl(f_k(x)\bigr)
$$
where
$$
f_k(x)=
\prod_{\large{j\in X_k}}
\frac
{x-j}
{k-j}
$$
For each $k\in\{0,...,p-1\}$, we have
$$
\prod_{\large{j\in X_k}}
(k-j)
\;
=
\;
\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}i
\;
=
\;
(p-1)!
$$
so by Wilson's theorem, the leading coefficient $b_k$ of $f_k$ is $-1$.

Then we get
\begin{align*}
a_{p-1}&=\,
\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}
P(k)(-1)
&&\bigl(\text{since $\deg{f_k}=p-1$ and $b_k=-1$}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
&=\,
-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}
P(k)
\\[4pt]
&=\,
-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}
k
&&\bigl(\text{since $P$ is a permutation of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
&=\,
-\frac{p(p-1)}{2}
\\[4pt]
&=\,
0
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
as was to be shown.